# Azure DevOps WorkItem Tracking not working when code generated

Tags: c#, api, azure-devops, nuget

I have a problem with azure devops workitem tracking.
So we want to use WorkItem tracking for work items, that do not need changes in our source code.

Currently we are tracking Builds and Releases with C# and the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking` NuGet packages.

The visualization for the build tracking is ok, but the deployments won´t show in the details pane of a ticket.

OK

[image: Ticket related with code]

Not OK

[image: Ticket related with CI/CD]

The relations both in azure devops and as shown in the debugger seem to be the same:

[image: Ticket Links from ticket related in code]

This is our patch operation:

```
new JsonPatchOperation()
                            {
                                Operation = Operation.Add,
                                Path = "/relations/-",
                                Value = new
                                {
                                    rel = "ArtifactLink",
                                    url = "vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/ReleaseEnvironment/" + temp.Href.Split('/')[4] + ":"+ release.Id + ":" + environment.Id, 
                                    attributes = new
                                    {
                                        authorizedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                        //comment = "This build was automatically linked to this work item based on the Tool",
                                        resourceCreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                        resourceModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                        name = "Integrated in release environment",
                                        revisedDate = new DateTime(9999, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

What should I do, to have the related Release displayed in the details pane of the ticket?
I compared every attribute while debugging with a sample ticket I created with CI/CD, every link and relation is OK. Builds are shown, releases not.

Comment: Do you mean you want to track a release associated with a work item from API? The screenshot with OK doesn't have deployment status, is that expected? Could you please elaborate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is not supported now. By default, the system has to create this link ([External link types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-type-reference?view=azure-devops#external-link-types)):

> Used to link a release to a work item. The system creates a link of
> this type when a user enables the Report deployment status to Work
> option for a release definition.

Additionally, your question from the community site as explanation: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/code-generated-relation-not-shown-in-workitem-trac/1096133